# How to translate Job 12:6c הֵבִ֖יא אֱלֹ֣והַּ בְּיָדֹֽו?

Tags: job

Job 12:6
New International Version

> a) The tents of marauders are undisturbed, b) and those who provoke God are secure-- c) those **God** has in his hand.

English Standard Version

> The tents of robbers are at peace, and those who provoke God are secure, who bring their **god** in their hand.

New King James Version

> The tents of robbers prosper, And those who provoke God are secure— In what **God** provides by His hand.

Does אֱל֣וֹהַּ refers to the LORD?

Comment: Job 12:9 answers this.

Comment: YLT : _He into whose hand God hath brought_. Greens Literal : _...to whomever God brings into his hand_.

Answer (score 3):

**Eloah אֱ֜ל֗וֹהַּ** refers to the **אֲדֹנֵ֣י הָֽאֲדֹנִ֑ים LORD [of] Lords**.

In Job 12:6 the phrase **" לַֽאֲשֶׁ֚ר הֵבִ֖יא **אֱל֣וֹהַּ** בְּיָדֽוֹ "** translated into English = **"to-whomever God brought [it] with-His-hand"**.

- Just like Job 33:12 " כִּֽי־יִרְבֶּ֥ה **אֱ֜ל֗וֹהַּ** מֵֽאֱנֽוֹשׁ " translates in English to " for God exceeds man ".

How do we know **Eloah אֱ֜ל֗וֹהַּ** refers to **יְ֝הוָה the LORD**? Because we read Job 12 completely to learn in **Job 12:9** : "Who among all these does not know that the hand of **YHVH** has done this?" ( מִ֭י לֹא־יָדַ֣ע בְּכָל־אֵ֑לֶּה כִּ֥י יַד־יְ֝הוָה עָ֣שְׂתָה זֹּֽאת )